# Different version of tcl giving different answers

Tags: regex, tcl, tclsh

I am running this function in tcl 8.0 verison.

```
proc test {} {
    set owner 212549316
    set val [regexp {[0-9]{9}} $owner]
    puts $val
}
```

The same code in tcl 8.6, the output is `1` but in tcl 8.0 it is `0`.
I am checking whether the string contains only 9 digits in tcl 8.0.

Any help how to make it work in tcl 8.0 verison.

Comment: Interesting. Does `[0-9]\{9\}` produce expected result in Tcl 8.0? From what [I see](http://www.wellho.net/regex/tcl.html), limiting quantifiers have been introduced in Tcl with version 8.1.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew this is giving 0 in both versions of tcl i.e 8.0 & 8.6.

Comment: So, the limiting (or *bound*) quantifier just is not supported in Tcl 8.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Tcl  8.0, *bound* (or *limiting*) quantifiers [are not supported](http://www.wellho.net/regex/tcl.html).

To  match 9 digits in Tcl 8.0, you'd have to repeat the `[0-9]` 9 times:

```
set val [regexp {[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]} $owner]
```

Bound quantifiers are supported starting with Tcl 8.1 with the introduction of *advanced regular expression* syntax.

Basic regex syntax available in Tcl 8.0 only includes:

```
.    Matches any character.
*    Matches zero or more instances of the previous pattern item.
+    Matches one or more instances of the previous pattern item.
?    Matches zero or one instances of the previous pattern item.
( )  Groups a subpattern. The repetition and alternation operators apply to the preceding subpattern.
|    Alternation.
[ ]  Delimit a set of characters. Ranges are specified as [x-y]. If the first character in the set is ^, then there is a match if the remaining characters in the set are not present.
^    Anchor the pattern to the beginning of the string. Only when first.
$    Anchor the pattern to the end of the string. Only when last.
```

See  [Practical Programming in Tcl and Tk, 3rd Ed.
© 1999, Brent Welch, Ch 11, p. 146](http://www.beedub.com/book/3rd/regexp.pdf).